# fit child form inside a certain dock panel in the parent form

Tags: wpf, parent-child

( using wpf ) Can some one tell me How to open child window from parent window and after opening it should be fit inside a dock panel in the Parent Window !!?

the Code is

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    chiledForm cw = new chiledForm ();
    cw.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    cw.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
    cw.Show();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You are talking about `MDI`, `WPF` doesn't support `MDI`!

Comment: thanks .. i think i will go back to winform

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve here is `MDI` which is a functionality available in `WinForms`.
`WPF` does not support that functionality instead you can use **[AvalonDock](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/)**
which offers similiar functionality.
I haven't used that personally so I can't guarantee it will fit your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

WPF has indeed no built-in support for Multiple Document Interface (MDI) but you could take a look at the following open source project:

**WPF Multiple Document Interface (MDI):** https://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/

It is a library to add the traditional Windows Forms Multiple Document Interface (MDI) features to WPF.